# WebSocket server can't receive message sended from ios client

Tags: ios, node.js, websocket

I use [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) to implement WebSocket Server and i successfully send message to my ios client(use [SocketRocket](https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket)
).However i can't send message to server or maybe server can't receive message sended from ios client.

WebSocket Server:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({port: 8080});

wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message,', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
    });
    ws.send("something");
});
```

I want to implement a websocket server that can exchange data with ios client.

Comment: Websocket server looks too simple, try adding more events listeners and use console.log to output more information. does the iOS client connect to server ?

Comment: Yes,client received the message:something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
    });
    ws.send("something");
});`

look at the callback `on('message',` you are defining an function an not an plain anonymous function to be used as callback also is `message` and not `message,` ( notice the comma).

Try the sample echo server to ensure everything is working, with your iOS client and you don't have any weird problems then proceed to further work on it.